# Seeming discrepancy between pKa and corresponding Ka of methylamine

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph

The first entry in PubChem for the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ of [methylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/methylamine#section=pKa) is $10.657$ at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. My elementary understanding is that this would be found as the negative log of the $K_\mathrm a,$ but the $K_\mathrm a$ is given as $2.70\times10^{-11}$ for which the negative log is about $10.568$.

My guess was that the two are determined independently, but can anyone shed some light on the seeming discrepancy?

Comment: A discrepancy of 0.1 in pKa is as good as no discrepancy at all.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Oh. They are each found experimentally...?

Comment: Maybe.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Humans create all that data. I'd guess that the 5 and 6 got transposed.